# Why fails 'include' with folder in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, permissions, include, include-path, php-5.4

In my local server, with PHP 5.3, if I do this:

```
    include('/folder/file.php');
```

Works fine. But in production server, using PHP 5.4, if I do the same, browser show this error:

> "include(/folder/file.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory"

"Folder" has 777 permissions.

I don't know what can I do

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `/` before `folder` implies it is at the root of the filesystem. Try `./folder`.

Comment: Thanks but this fails too, the file who contains "include" is in the same floor that "folder", and this works fine in test server with php 5.3

Answer (score 0):

include('/folder/file.php'); 
is including a file located at

```
localhost/folder/file.php
```

make sure you are in the right directory.
you can try

```
include('./folder/file.php');
```

or

```
include('../folder/file.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 include("/folder/file.php");
```

Comment: what difference double quotes is going to make?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
include "$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/folder/file.php";
```